# How to make routeParams optional

Tags: javascript, angularjs, routes

So i have this route in angular

And the problem is that the :volume is not always available from the api that i am using 
Sometimes the volume is there and sometimes not 
So is it possible that i can make the :volume parm optional so that it wil only show it when it is there and when it is not given that it will remove it

The url when a book has a volume is `book/read/:name/:volume/:chapter/:id`

And when it doesn't has a volume it is `book/read/:name/:chapter/:id`

```
    'use strict';

angular.module('myApp.read', [])

.config( function($stateProvider) {
    $stateProvider.state('read', {
        url: '/read/:name/:volume?/:chapter/:id',
        templateUrl: 'pages/read/read.html',
        controller: 'ReadController',
        onEnter: function($rootScope){
            $rootScope.bodyClass = 'read';
        }
    });
})

.controller('ReadController', function($scope, $http, $stateParams, $state) {
    var name = $stateParams.name; //getting name
    var volume = $stateParams.volume; //getting volume
    var chapter = $stateParams.chapter; //getting chapter
    var id = $stateParams.id; //getting id

    $scope.state = $state.current;
    $scope.params = $stateParams;

    if (volume && volume.length) volume += '/';

    $http.get('http://localhost:1337/book/read/' + name + '/' + volume + chapter + '/' + id).success(function(response) {
        $scope.read = response;
    });

});
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure about one in the middle of a set, but to make a parameter optional all you do is follow it with a `?` so yours would be: `url: '/read/:name/:volume?/:chapter/:id'`

And, of course, you'd have to update the controller to handle it not existing. For example:

```
.controller('ReadController', function($scope, $http, $stateParams, $state) {
    var name = $stateParams.name; //getting name
    var volume = $stateParams.volume; //getting volume
    var chapter = $stateParams.chapter; //getting chapter
    var id = $stateParams.id; //getting id

    $scope.state = $state.current;
    $scope.params = $stateParams;

    if (volume && volume.length) volume += '/';

    $http.get('http://localhost:1337/book/read/' + name + '/' + volume + chapter + '/' + id).success(function(response) {
        $scope.read = response;
    });

});
```

Comment: Edited to add example. Basically, only include the slash if `volume` was set.

Comment: I think i am doing some thing wrong this is the url i get from the api `http://localhost:1337/book/read/:name/:chapter/:id` I edited the question to what i have now